# Getting Error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" in Laravel while sending Email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

I have an online appointment form from where user can take appointment. An email will be generated after taking appointment. But getting below error while sending email.

> Trying to access array offset on value of type null

**store function inside appointment controller**

```
$emailDataArray = array(
    'appointment_id' => $lastInsertedId,
    'patient_name' => $request->appointment_name,
    'patient_number' => $request->appointment_contact_no,
    'patient_age' => $request->appointment_age,
    'patient_gender' => $request->appointment_gender,
    'branch_name' => $branch_name->name,
    'doctor_name' => $doctor_name->name,
    'schedule_date' => $request->schedule_date,
    'schedule_time' => $schedule_time->schedule_time,
    'purpose' => $purpose->about_us,
);
$email = $this->sendMail($emailDataArray);
```

**sendMail function inside appointment controller**

```
Mail::send('frontend.mail.mail', $emailDataArray, function($message) use ($emailDataArray)
{
    $message->to('arafat@lasermedicalbd.com')->subject('APPOINTMENT');
    $message->from('arafat@lasermedicalbd.com');
});
```

**mail.blade.php**

```
<p>PATIENT NAME &#09;: {{ $patient_name }}</p>
<p>PATIENT NUMBER &#09;: {{ $patient_number }}</p>
<p>PATIENT AGE &#09;: {{ $patient_age }}</p>
<p>PATIENT GENDER &#09;: {{ $patient_gender] }}</p>
<p>BRANCH NAME &#09;: {{ $branch_name }}</p>
<p>DOCTOR NAME &#09;: {{ $doctor_name}}</p> 
<p>DATE &#09;: {{ $schedule_date }}</p>
<p>TIME &#09;: {{ $schedule_time }}</p>
<p>PURPOSE &#09;: {{ $purpose }}</p>
```

How to solve this? Anybody Help please?

Comment: Start with a var_dump on the $emailDataArray to see what’s being sent to your mail template. Then check to see your mail template isn’t trying to access an index in your associative array that might not exist.

Comment: @FilmJ....where use `var_dump`.... in mail.blade.php?

Answer (score 0):

It's spelled incorrectly here:

```
<p>PATIENT GENDER &#09;: {{ $patient_gende] }}</p>
```

Change it into:

```
<p>PATIENT GENDER &#09;: {{ $patient_gender }}</p>
```

Comment: Tran....It's a typo in the post..... in main code it is ok.